# Gradle SSH plugin transfer file from local to remote vm

Tags: gradle, ssh

I am trying to transfer a file from my local machine to remote machine by using Gradle SSH plugin.
*This is my code:*

```
//build.gradle
plugins {
  id 'org.hidetake.ssh' version '2.9.0'
}


// Global settingsl
ssh.settings {
  knownHosts = allowAnyHosts    // Disable host key verification
}

// Add a remote host
ssh.remotes {
  webServer {
    host = '52.xxx.xxx.xxx'
    user = 'me'
    password = 'xxxxx'
  }
}

task deploy() << {
  ssh.run {
    session(ssh.remotes.webServer) {
      put 'D:\\a\\a.txt', 'C:/webapps'
    }
  }
}
```

when I am running deploy task then I am getting following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':deploy'.
```

> com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

So, can anyone please tell me the solution
if I need to configure something in windows then please give me a solution.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your target machine is Windows. 
I guess there is no SSH server running there. Use your favorite search engine looking for "windows ssh server" if you don't know what to do.

Just my two cents: 
The name webServer might be misleading here, as far as this server is not in the role of a webserver within your infrastructure. You should prefer the java/groovy like file descriptions over the windows specific. At least the destination path, your second put parameter, will probably not work with SSH.